# Mensaje en WordPress por error en functions.php en REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, wordpress

¿Que significa este mensaje en Wordpress?

```
constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PruebaWordPressBridge\wp-content\themes\twentynineteen\functions.php
```

¿Debo cambiar el archivo functions.php de REQUEST_URI A 'REQUEST_URI' del tema en cuestion?

Answer (score 1):

- Así en el archivo function.php:
  remplaza  $ _SERVER [REQUEST_URI] por $ _SERVER ['REQUEST_URI']
- Esto va desde (PHP 4 >= 4.1.0, PHP 5, PHP 7)
- 'REQUEST_URI'
  La URI que se empleó para acceder a la página. Por ejemplo: '/index.html'.
- Para mas información de como pasar los parámetros a la variable podrias checarlo en su 
  pagina oficial de php: 
  https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php